# How to determine the type of data in the ResultSet?

Tags: java

I get the results of the query to the database in the form of a `ResultSet` object. A field in a database of different types, and obviously I don't know what the query will be executed and what the ResultSet will be passed to my function.

Regardless of the data type of the column in the `ResultSet`, this information can be obtained as a string or a number, or date. To do this, use the methods `getString(int)`, `getInt(int)`, etc.

How to know what type of data is in that column, and depending on it to use different methods to get the data?

Comment: Use a __switch__ control statement following an __instanceof__ statement.

Comment: It isn't at all obvious that you don't know the query to be expected or the types of the result columns. The premiss of JDBC is that you know both.

Comment: @EJP: Hmmm ... so you mean general query applications like sqldeveloper and similar may not be written using JDBC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use to retrieve the value of the `getObject` method, and then define the type (`getClass` or `instanceof`). Note the documentation for the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
java.sql 
Interface ResultSetMetaData
```

An object that can be used to get information about the types and properties of the columns in a ResultSet object. Then choose get-method based on info retrieved from `ResultSetMetaData`. There are examples available. Also look at this [How can I get different datatypes from ResultSetMetaData in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367828/how-can-i-get-different-datatypes-from-resultsetmetadata-in-java)