# How to check if existing database matches program's format

Tags: sql, derby, javadb

First, I'm new to Java DB programming so maybe my approach is wrong. So please keep that in mind. Now the question:

My program let's the user open an existing Java Derby database. When it's opened I want to check if the database contains the correct tables and each table has the correct columns - not just names but type also. So far I'm trying to create each table and if it throws an exception then I know the table exists. Now I need to check column types. What is the best practice to do this? Hard-code check for each column type as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367828/how-can-i-get-different-datatypes-from-resultsetmetadata-in-java) in the catch block?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to figure out what tables are present in the database, and what columns each table has, etc., there are (at least) two simple approaches:

1. Issue SQL queries against the Derby system catalogs, such as

   select s.schemaname || '.' || t.tablename
    from sys.systables t, sys.sysschemas s
    where t.schemaid = s.schemaid 
         and t.tabletype = 'T' 
    order by s.schemaname, t.tablename;
2. Use the API provided by `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData`, and its methods such as `getSchemas()`, `getTables()`, and `getColumns()`